# Let $G = \text {Gal}(L/K)$. How do I see that $\phi \in G$ is completely determined by $\phi\mathbb( \sqrt[4] {3})$ and $\phi(i)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, galois-theory

Let $K = \mathbb Q$ and $L = \mathbb( \sqrt[4] {3}, i)$. I see that $L \supset K$ is a an Galois extension. Also, after computations I've $[L : K] = 8$ (degree of $L$ over $K$ considered as a vector space).

Let $G = \text {Gal}(L/K)$.

**How do I see that $\phi \in G$ is completely determined by $\phi\mathbb( \sqrt[4] {3})$ and $\phi(i)$ ?**

I see that if $\mathbb {\sqrt[4] {3}}, i, 1$ is a basis for $L$ over $K$ then it must be true, since $x = a_1 \mathbb { \sqrt[4] {3} } + a_2 i + a_3 1$ for every $x \in L$ with $a_i \in K$, but this is not the case since the degree of $L$ over $K$ is $8$.

Comment: Sorry, I did a typo. It has been corrected.

Comment: Your question is basically an instance of the general theme in algebra: **A homomorphism from an algebraic structure is completely determined by the images of generators.** You have undoubtedly seen instances of this before. A linear transformation is fully determined once you give the images of the elements in a basis. A homomorphism from a cyclic group to any group is fully determined once you know the image of the generator, et cetera. That is what we seek to convey, when we say that a structure is generated by certain elements.

Comment: But how do I know the generators ? If I knew a basis it would be straight forward. For example in $\mathbb C$, if I know the image of $1$ and $i$ I know everything about the automorphism.

Comment: (cont'd) Note that here normality of the extension makes no difference to this very general principle. Normality is very useful though. When we can deduce that a finite extension is Galois, then we know that the number of automorphisms is equal to the degree. This often allows us to deduce things such as "all combinations of these maps occur".

Comment: see my comment on top of yours.

Comment: When we denote a field $L=\Bbb{Q}(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n)$, then the elements $a_1,a_2,\ldots, a_n$ are automatically a set of generators. In that case $L$ is called "the smallest extension of $\Bbb{Q}$ containing $a_1,\ldots,a_n$" or "the field extension *generated by* $a_1,\ldots,a_n$." It isn't by any means necessary that the set of generators is minimal. In the case of vector spaces and linear transformations we can define the images of a set larger than a basis. Then we are not guaranteed to get a well defined homomorphism. **That** is the real difficulty (even more so for fields and groups).

Comment: Shouldn't one give a proof of the claim that the homomorphism is determined by these generators ?

Comment: No I only have notes.

Comment: Thank you very much. Otherwise can you recommend a book with a proof ?

Comment: I would expect that most books describe the idea. It is better that you ask your teacher for a book that is a good fit for the material s/he is planning on covering.

Answer (score 2):

With $L=\Bbb Q(\sqrt[4]3)$ it's $[L:K]=4$ not $8$. But maybe you mean $L=\Bbb Q(\sqrt[4]3,i)$. In this last case the degree over $\Bbb Q$ is $8$ and this last one is a NORMAL extension of $\Bbb Q$ and this is necessary in order to consider Galois extensions: if $L$ is not normal (like $L=\Bbb Q(\sqrt[4]3)$) the Galois correspondance isn't guaranteed.

Said so, an automorphism $\phi\in G=\operatorname{Gal}(L|K)$ (with $L=\Bbb Q(\sqrt[4]3,i)$) is totally determined by knowing where $i$ and $\sqrt[4]3$ go because it's first of all an homomorphism which fixes pointwise $\Bbb Q$.

Explicitely, every element of $L$ is a linear combination of $1$ and powers of $i$ and $\sqrt[4]3$, with coefficients in $\Bbb Q$. To be more precise a base of $L$ over $K$ is given by
$$
\{1,\sqrt[4]3,(\sqrt[4]3)^2,(\sqrt[4]3)^3,i,i\sqrt[4]3,i(\sqrt[4]3)^2,i(\sqrt[4]3)^3\}
$$
hence by the properties of homomorphisms like $\phi(a_0i(\sqrt[4]3)^2)=
\phi(a_0)\phi(i)\phi((\sqrt[4]3)^2)=a_0\phi(i)(\phi(\sqrt[4]3))^2$ ($a_0\in\Bbb Q$) you can see that the knowledge of $\phi(i)$ and $\phi(\sqrt[4]3)$, the automorphism is totally determined.

Comment: Indeed it should be $L = \mathbb Q(\sqrt [4]{3}, i)$.

Comment: I have some questions: "If $L$ is not normal the Galois correspondance isn't guaranteed" - of course not, $L$ need to be normal in order to be Galois ?

How do you see every element of $L$ is a linear combination of $1$ and powers of $i$ and $\sqrt [4] {3}$ with coefficients in $\mathbb Q$ ? If I knew this, it would be much more easy to realize my question.

How do you know this is a basis for $L$ over $K$ ? Do you use a theorem or ?

Thanks for your answer !

Comment: See my second answer below

Answer (score 1):

Extending the comments to an answer.

Assume that a field $F$ is given as a subset of a bigger field $\Omega$. Let $S$ be a subset of $\Omega$. We denote by $F(S)$ the smallest subfield of $\Omega$ containing both $F$ and $S$. We can do that because such a thing exists. Namely $F(S)$ is the intersection of all those subfields of $\Omega$ that contain both $F$ and $S$. It follows easily from the subfield criterion that such an intersection is a subfield.

**Lemma.** If $S=\{a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n\}$ then
$$
F(S)=\left\{\frac{P(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n)}{Q(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n)}\,\bigg\vert\,
P,Q\in F[x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n], Q(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n)\neq0\right\}.
$$

**Proof.** Denote the set given above by $K$. Because $F(S)$ is a field, it is closed under multiplication. Therefore it contains all monomials $c a_1^{k_1}a_2^{k_2}\cdots a_n^{k_n}$, where $c\in F$ is arbitrary and $k_i,i=1,2,\ldots,n,$ are arbitrary non-negative integers.
Because $F(S)$ is closed under addition it must also contain all the elements
$P(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n)\in\Omega$ for all the polynomials $P\in F[x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n]$.
Because $F(S)$ closed under division by non-zero elements it must contain all the fractions $P(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n)/Q(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n)$ listed above. So $K\subseteq F(S)$.

If we can show that $K$ is a subfield then the claim follows because clearly $K$ contains both $F$ and $S$. This is an immediate consequence of the subfield criterion and is left as an exercise. This implies that $F(S)\subseteq K$. Therefore $K=F(S)$. **QED**

**Proposition.** Assume that $F$, $S$ and $\Omega$ are as in the above lemma. Assume that we are given elements $b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_n\in\Omega$. Then there exists at most one $F$-homomorphism of fields $\phi:F(S)\to\Omega$ such that
$\phi(a_i)=b_i$ for all $i=1,2,\ldots,n$.

**Proof.** Assume that such a homomorphism exists (Note: this is not at all clear and for most choices of elements $b_i$ it does not exist). Because $\phi$ is an $F$-homomorphism, we have $\phi(c)=c$ for all $c\in F$. Because $\phi$ respects multiplication we have for all $c\in F$ is and all non-negative integers $k_i,i=1,2,\ldots,n,$ that
$$
\begin{aligned}
\phi(c a_1^{k_1}a_2^{k_2}\cdots a_n^{k_n})&=\phi(c)\phi(a_1)^{k_1}\cdots\phi(a_n)^{k_n}\\
&=cb_1^{k_1}b_2^{k_2}\cdots b_n^{k_n}.
\end{aligned}
$$
Because $\phi$ also respects sums we get from this that for all the polynomials
$P\in F[x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n]$ we must have
$$
\phi(P(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n))=P(b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_n).
$$
We just proved this when $P$ is a monomial and any polynomial is a finite sum of monomials, so this is clear.

Because a homomorphism of fields maps a non-zero element to a non-zero element we can conclude that if $Q(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n)\neq0$, then also
$$
0\neq\phi(Q(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n))=Q(b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_n).
$$
Because a homomorphism of fields maps a quotient of two elements to the quotient of the images of those elements we deduce that we must have
$$
\phi\left(\frac{P(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n)}{Q(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n)}\right)=
\frac{P(b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_n)}{Q(b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_n)}.
$$
In the preceding Lemma we saw that all the elements $z\in F(S)$ are of the form
$z=P(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n)/Q(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n)$ for some polynomials $P,Q$. We have shown that the image of $\phi(z)$ is fully determined. **QED**

Comment: I want to emphasize that the more difficult and more interesting game is played when trying to figure out which choices $b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_n\in\Omega$ actually work and yield a homomorphism of fields. In the case of number fields we can use $\Omega=\Bbb{C}$. The $\Omega$ is there to provide a playground so that we don't have to worry whether all those operations are available to us. Any big field will serve in its role.

Answer (score 0):

$L$ need to be normal because otherwise it wouldn't make sense to consider *automorphisms* of $L$. Take $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]2)$: in order to have an automorphism $\sqrt[3]2$ must go in one of its conjugates, which are $\sqrt[3]2,\omega\sqrt[3]2,\omega^2\sqrt[3]2$ where $\omega=e^{\frac{2\pi i}{3}}$. But $\sqrt[3]2\mapsto\omega\sqrt[3]2$ is NOT an automorphism of $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]2)$.

Every element of $L$ is a linear combination of $1$ and powers of $i$ and $\sqrt[4]3$ with coefficients in $\Bbb Q$ by definition of $\Bbb K(\alpha)$ where $\Bbb K$ is a field and $\alpha$ is an algebraic element over $\Bbb K$.
This follows from:

1. $\Bbb Q[\sqrt[4]3,i]=\Bbb Q(\sqrt[4]3,i)$ (see [showing $Q[\sqrt 2] = Q(\sqrt 2)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/740679/showing-q-sqrt-2-q-sqrt-2/740714#740714)).
2. $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[4]3,i)=\Bbb Q(\sqrt[4]3)(i)$
3. if $\alpha$ is algebraic over $\Bbb K$ of degree $n$ then $\Bbb K[\alpha]=\{x_0+x_1\alpha+x_2\alpha^2+\dots+x_{n-1}\alpha^{n-1}\;\;|\;\;x_i\in\Bbb K\}$